# Datatype mismatch beautifulsoup TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a segment of code that visits `link`s and tries to find certain `keywords` in each `link`.

Finally, if a `link` has *one or more* of the `keywords` it stores it in a `list`.

However, when I run my code it gives me an issue of:
`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` on this line:

```
for a in soup.find_all('a', class_="result-title hdrlnk", text=re.compile(job_kw,re.IGNORECASE)):
```

Here is the code:

```
jobs_by_city = [
'http://boston.website.org/search/widget',
]

job_kw = [['web site','user', 'account'],['permission', 'name']]
job_kw = sum(job_kw, [])

jobs = []

for job_in_city in jobs_by_city:
    a_job = requests.get(job_in_city)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(a_job.text, "lxml")
    for a in soup.find_all('a', class_="result-title hdrlnk", text=re.compile(job_kw,re.IGNORECASE)):
        print(a.get('href'))
        #jobs.append(a.get('href'))
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Which "Beautiful Soup" version are you using ?  `re.compile` doesn't take a list as the pattern. i think you can just pass the list as the `text` argument. in BS v4 you can pass a list to `string` argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.compile` does not take `list` as input. You have to iterate over the key words:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

jobs_by_city = [
'http://boston.website.org/search/widget',
]

job_kws = [['web site','user', 'account'],['permission', 'name']]
job_kws = sum(job_kws, [])

jobs = []

for job_in_city in jobs_by_city:
    a_job = requests.get(job_in_city)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(a_job.text, "lxml")
    for job_kw in job_kws:
        for a in soup.find_all('a', class_="result-title hdrlnk", text=re.compile(job_kw,re.IGNORECASE)):
            print(a.get('href'))
            #jobs.append(a.get('href'))
```

*The given url does not provide the html elements you are looking for :)*